# Mobx autorun based on computed value being true

Tags: javascript, mobx, autorun, mobx-state-tree

I'm still fairly new to MobX, I understand the concepts of computed, autorun, observables. But I'm struggling with a certain scenario. I have the following code in my store (I'm using mobx-state-tree) :

```
export const store = types
    .model({
        renderingState: types.optional(types.string, 'stage1'),
        containerMounted: types.optional(types.boolean, false),
    })
    .views(self => ({
        //computed value
        isReady() {
            if (self.renderingState === 'stage3' && self.containerMounted) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }))
```

Now essentially, I want to run a function `loadConfigurations` when the computed value is true. In this scenario I want to run my function when renderingState is stage3 and containerMounted is true. From my understanding of autorun, it will fire as soon as the computed value changes. But I would like my function to fire when the if statement is valid.

If you have any insight or could help clarify any misconception I have that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is that your `isReady` property is not computed. To make it a computed it should be like this

```
    .views(self => ({
        //computed value
        get isReady(): boolean {
            if (self.renderingState === 'stage3' && self.containerMounted) {
                return true;
            }

            // add the default value
            return false;
        }
    }))
```

Now that the isReady is a computed property you can simply use it inside autorun

```
autorun(() => {
    if (myStore.isReady) {
        // your logic goes inside the if
        console.log("My store is ready")
    }
})
```

OR

```
autorun(() => {
    if (!myStore.isReady) {
        return false
    }

    // your logic goes here
})
```

The function inside `autorun` will run every time isReady changes it's value, true/false
When it goes from false to true the logic will get executed.

TBH I don't really use `autorun`, I like to use `reaction` inside the `afterCreate` method like this

```
export const store = types
    .model({
        renderingState: types.optional(types.string, 'stage1'),
        containerMounted: types.optional(types.boolean, false),
    })
    .actions(self => ({
      afterCreate() {
        addDisposer(self, reaction(
          () => {
            return self.isReady
          },
          () => {
            if (self.isReady) {
              // your logic should go here
            }
          }
        ))  
      }
    }))
    .views(self => ({
        //computed value
        get isReady() {
            if (self.renderingState === 'stage3' && self.containerMounted) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }))
```

Comment: is addDisposer built in function in mobx?

Comment: @Pavan addDisposer is a built in function of mobx-state-tree https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/API/#adddisposer